# Find the surface area of $z = y^2$ over region R in xy plane with vertices $A(0,0) B(0,2),C(2,2)$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Here is what I have so far:

$$ F_z(y,z) = 1, \space F_y(y,z) = 2y \\ S = \int\int_D \sqrt{1 + 2y^2} dA$$

What would the bounds be for the double integral ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your region is defined by $0\leq x\leq y$ and $0\leq y\leq 2$, or alternatively, $0\leq x\leq 2$ and $x\leq y\leq 2$. The integral is therefore
$$\int_0^2\int_0^y\sqrt{1+2y^2}\,dx\,dy$$
or
$$\int_0^2\int_x^2\sqrt{1+2y^2}\,dy\,dx.$$